# Identify this movie - a robot with a hypodermic needle that causes hallucinations

Tags: story-identification, movie, technology, robots

I am looking for the name of a movie.

One of the scenes involves a robot that possesses a kind of hypodermic needle, which injects a substance that causes very intense hallucinations, eventually leading to death.  I believe that in this scene a man who is injected begins to fall to the drug's effect and in order to counteract the drug's effect, he begins to cut off his arm with a knife.

The depiction of the experience is quite intense and very dark, so that at one point during the height of the effect of the drug the scene shows the robot as a kind of surreal, ominous presence as seen from the perspective of the man who was injected.

Comment: Try editing your title.  It has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: do you have any idea of the age of the movie? was it in English or was it a non-English production?

Comment: This really sounds more like some Japanese movie, do you know around what year you saw it and a rough guess as to the year the movie came out.

Answer (score 4):

It might be *[Hardware](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Hardware)*, a 1990 British film. One of the robot's abilities was to inject a victim with a poison that caused hallucinations as their nervous system degraded. It was partially based off of a *2000 AD* comic and involved a desert scavenger artist who tried to assemble some wreckage he found into a sculpture and instead got a killer robot.

> The robot is eventually defeated by, of all things, a shower head. Apparently, it was not water-proof.

From the [IMDB Parent's Guide for the film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099740/parentalguide):

> A character **cuts his own arm with a large knife. The first cut is seen from a distance, while the next one is a close-up and the knife cuts deeper**...

**Trailer**:

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely [THX-1138](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/thx1138.txt).  It matches all of the plot elements.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qF8vKu8Do5Q) is another link to Lucas discussing the torture scenes.