# Trying to ID film based on poster; robot or cyborg themed?

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, cyborg

Back in the early to mid 90s, I saw this video at Blockbuster all the time and thought it looked interesting; but it also looked "scary" and I knew my overprotective mom would never let me rent it.

It showed what looked like a robot or cyborg hand; the fingers were dark, metallic and pointy, rather like Freddy Krueger knives (but I know this wasn't one of the *A Nightmare On Elm Street* films).  Most of the fingers were folded back, but the index finger was extended downward and just starting to poke into some water (oil?), which was rippling.

By the time I was old enough to rent it myself, it was gone (as Blockbuster itself is now, of course).  Does this sound familiar at all to anyone?  I'm sorry I don't remember anything else.

Comment: :) Great minds...

Comment: Yeah, that's not it; it was JUST the hand and the water/oil in extreme close-up, nothing else.  Thanks though!

Comment: Well, [here's a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_films_of_the_1990s). Dig in! :)

Comment: That list sure helped, it led me right to it!  See below and thanks!

Comment: Film identification is probably more appropriate on Movies/TV...

Comment: Story-identification: "Questions asking for help identifying a TV series/episode, comic-book issue/story arc, **movie**, book, or other story."

Comment: I've marked this one as a dupe of a newer question/answer that has more detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it!  I was a little off on the description, but it's called [Death Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Machine)!  Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't match the water/oil, but could this be a movie poster for *[Hardware](http://www.sinfulcelluloid.com/2012/12/no-flesh-shall-be-spared-hardware-1990.html#.U6Q3I_ldXRs)*? It looks very Freddy-Kruger-esque to me.

[image: Hardware movie poster]

Comment: No, that's not it, it's just the hand and the water/oil/mystery liquid in close-up.  Thanks though!

Comment: [It's not always _Hardware_!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/56860/19561)

Comment: @SQB:
^_^ No, it is not... but it's surprising how often it's an appropriate answer. As a matter of disclosure, I've never actually seen *Hardware*. I only know about it because it keeps coming up in search results.

Comment: *Hardware* is apparently the [lupus](http://theconversation.com/why-its-never-lupus-television-illness-and-the-making-of-a-meme-1198) of sci-fi movies.

Answer (score 3):

[Edward Scissorhands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Scissorhands)?

Matches your description though I couldn't find an exact image match (eg finger in liquid).

[image: Movie poster]

Comment: Until I just found the right answer (see above), I actually was beginning to think it might be Edward Scissorhands and my childhood brain had just mangled the poster.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be [Death Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Machine)? Released in 1994.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but this answer was already given about an hour ago.

Comment: That's what I get for not refreshing the page before answering.